# Adding custom layouts for CMS and Category use with custom module trouble

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, module, template, page-layouts

I have a category in my store that requires a totally different layout to the standard Magento layouts. So I created a new copy of the 1column.phtml and renamed it and made one small change to test.

Now the problem is that the custom layout is not showing up. I created a module (which is working as it is seen in the Admin > Config > Advanced overview).

My files and contents are as follows:

**app/etc/modules/Test_Page.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Test_Page>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Page />
            </depends>
        </Test_Page>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Test/Page/etc/config.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Test_Page>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Test_Page>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <page>
            <layouts>
                <homepage module="page" translate="label">
                    <label>Homepage</label>
                    <template>page/home.phtml</template>
                    <layout_handle>homepage</layout_handle>
                </homepage>

                <!-- add more layouts here -->
            </layouts>
        </page>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <Test_Page>
                    <file>test_page.xml</file>
                </Test_Page>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**app/design/frontend/test/default/layout/test_page.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?> 
<layout>
    <homepage translate="label">
        <label>Home Page</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/home.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
        </reference>
    </homepage> 
</layout>
```

I can't see anything I've screwed up, It's being read as a module but the custom layout is not being shown up :(

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In order to make it appear in the layout dropdown you need to create a custom module (you can also add something in a core file but please don't do that).
Let's name the extension Easylife_Layout.
For this you need to create the following files:
`app/etc/modules/Easylife_Layout.xml` - the declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Layout>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Page />
            </depends>
        </Easylife_Layout>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/Layout/etc/config.xml` - the configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Layout>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Easylife_Layout>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <page>
            <layouts> 
                <lookbook module="page" translate="label">
                    <label>Lookbook</label>
                    <template>page/1column-lookbook.phtml</template>
                    <layout_handle>lookbook</layout_handle>
                </lookbook> 
            </layouts>
        </page>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <easylife_layout>
                    <file>easylife_layout.xml</file>
                </easylife_layout>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

`app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/layout/easylife_layout.xml` - the layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<layout>
    <lookbook translate="label">
        <label>Lookbook</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column-lookbook.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
        </reference>
    </lookbook> 
</layout>
```

The last one is necessary in case you want to be able to reference your custom layout in layout files. Something like:

```
<update hande="lookbook" />
```

Clear the cache and...that's it.
Le tme know if it works for you.

Comment: logging in and out did the trick for me after this

Answer (score 6):

There are two possibilities:

1. You add a custom layout to your category and do this:

   ```
   <layout>
       <reference name="root">
           <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column-lookbook.phtml</template></action>
       </reference>
   </layout>
   ```
2. You implement it as a page layout and add it to the `config.xml` in `global/page/layouts/` but I don't know, how to do it exactly.

If you only need it once, you can stay with the first solution. But be careful. There are `<action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>` in the `page.xml` Sometimes this setting prevents the change of the template.

To do the first solution:
Select your category, got to `Custom Design` and put everything inside the `<layout />` node into the `Custom Layout Update` textarea, e.g.:

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setBackgroundGraphic">
        <background>two-pieces</background>
    </action>
    <action method="setTemplate">
    <template>page/2columns-right-highStep.phtml</template>
    </action>
    <action method="setIsHandle">
        <applied>1</applied>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Comment: Where would I have to stick the layout reference for the first one? I tried very similar code in layout.xml but had no idea what level to place it, i have references there for all category pages as default using <catalog_category_view> so i assumed i need something similar to add another option

Comment: edited the answer