# top links only loading log in link

Tags: module, layout, toplinks

I'm writing a new layout file for a custom module. As part of this I need to include the toplinks eg. log in, cart + (quantity), my account, wishlist and also recently viewed and nothing else. My layout file looks like so,

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <layout version="0.1.0">
<dynamicblocks_index_index>
    <block type="core/template" name="root" output="toHtml" template="dynamicblocks/index.phtml" >
        <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
        <block type="reports/product_viewed" before="right.permanent.callout" name="right.reports.product.viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />
    </block>
</dynamicblocks_index_index>
```

I got the link for loading the toplinks from page.xml

```
  <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
```

I am sure this is what loads the correct information on the main pages as when I comment it out all of the top links disappear. But in my custom layout it is only able to load one link (login). I also can't see how my layout file is wrong or reference incorrectly as it loads the recently viewed products as I expected.

The issue I'm having is that the top links is only returning the log in link. Any ideas on this?

Comment: `top links is only returning the log in link`? I'm not getting it

Comment: in the page.xml layout it returns -> log in, my account, checkout, cart and my wishlist.

Comment: is there any reference you are looking at? for new layout file.

Comment: by reference what do you mean, reference tag? if so no

Comment: is there any blog you are following for doing this?

Comment: i've found information from various sources. I'm hoping to get a direct answer on what this should return and why it behaves differently in one layout to another. That's a little bit too specific to hope to get from a tutorial

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13726/discussion-between-mohammad-faisal-and-thomas-ryan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the page to just display the links that i wanted I had to tell the xml to remove certain files. This is my updated xml

```
  <dynamicblocks_index_index>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>dynamicblocks/index.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>   

    <reference name="header">
        <remove name="store_language" />
        <remove name="catalog.topnav" />
        <remove name="top.search" />
    </reference>

    <!-- <block type="reports/product_viewed" before="right.permanent.callout" name="right.reports.product.viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" /> -->

</dynamicblocks_index_index>
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the [discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13726/discussion-between-mohammad-faisal-and-thomas-ryan).

> Before continuing you must check this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/1147/4426) in order to properly add the new layout template.

Your layout file should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <dynamicblocks_index_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>module/file/path/template.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </dynamicblocks_index_index>
</layout>
```

And in your template file you told that the code written is: `$this->getChildHtml();`
Actually the problem there is that you had not specified the name of the block, that's why you are getting everything whether you just need the **top links**. So the code in your template file might look like:

```
$this->getChildHtml('top.links');
```