# Can I increase the width of the column layout on default magento theme

Tags: layout, column, default

I want to know is there a way to increase the default width of the columns in magento default theme, version 1.8.1? If so, where do i access this information and how do i update it? I know that by default we have 2 column with right bar.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the width in the stylesheets:-

```
.col-main {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
}

.col-right {
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

Just adjust the percentages to the width you want them to occupy.

Alternatively, rather than modifying the width of the columns in the `2-column-left`, `2-column-right` or `3-columns` layouts, you could [create your own custom layout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/1147/798)...