# Where do I specify the file path for phtml? (Clarification please)

Tags: module, magento-1, attributes, custom, phtml

Where do I put the phtml file that all of this works with?

Current Files and their folder structure:
app/code/local/Sean/Customform/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php
class Sean_Customform_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
    public function indexAction(){ //this will display the form
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('core/session'); //this will allow flash messages
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
    public function sendAction(){ //handles the form submit
        $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
        $post = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();

        $customer->setData('vendorMarkup', $post['vendorMarkup']);
        $customer->setData('vendorGramPrice', $post['vendorGramPrice']);
        $customer->setData('vendorGramFront', $post['vendorGramFront']);
        $customer->setData('vendorGramBack', $post['vendorGramBack']);
        $customer->setData('vendorDefaultCalc', $post['defaultMarkup']);
        $customer->save();

        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($this->__('Your Calculator Preferences Are Updated!'));//add success message.
        $this->_redirect('*/*');
    }
}
```

app/code/local/Sean/Customform/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sean_Customform>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Sean_Customform>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <customform><!-- block alias -->
                <class>Sean_Customform_Block</class>
            </customform>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <customform><!-- helper alias -->
                <class>Sean_Customform_Helper</class>
            </customform>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customform>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Sean_Customform</module>
                    <frontName>customform</frontName><!-- url key for module -->
                </args>
            </customform>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <sean_customform>
                    <file>sean_customform.xml</file><!-- frontend layout file -->
                </sean_customform>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Sean_Customform>
                    <files>
                        <default>Sean_Customform.csv</default><!-- translation file (not mandatory) -->
                    </files>
                </Sean_Customform>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Sean/Customform/helper.Data.php

```
<?php
class Sean_Customform_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{
}
```

And of course, app/etc/modules/Sean_Customform.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sean_Customform>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Sean_Customform>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Please enable the template path hints to check from which path template is showing.

Comment: I enabled them.

Comment: The path template is: frontend/base/default/template/sean_customform/form.phtml

Comment: All I want to know is what creates that path, and where is it specified?

Comment: <layout>
            <updates>
                <sean_customform>
                    <file>sean_customform.xml</file><!-- frontend layout file -->
                </sean_customform>
            </updates>
        </layout>

Comment: in this layout file sean_customform.xml you have mention the block class name . from that block class your phtml file are rendering which you mention in your block .

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/79219)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `config.xml` file, you have this part.

```
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <sean_customform>
                <file>sean_customform.xml</file><!-- frontend layout file -->
            </sean_customform>
        </updates>
    </layout>
```

This defines a frontend layout xml file `sean_customform.xml` which is going to hold all frontend layout definition specifically for your module. You can find this file at location `app/design/frontend/base/default/sean_customform.xml`.

Here you will find your `form.phtml` file inclusion.

So basically you have a dedicated layout xml for your module and all module related layout definition is going to happen in that layout xml file (in this case, it is `sean_customform.xml`). This file will hold all phtml files.

Comment: Could I name the phtml file anything I want? As long as its in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sean_customform?

Comment: Yes you can give any name for your phtml file. But that name change you need to specify in `app/design/frontend/base/default/sean_customform.xml` too.

Comment: I guess why I'm confused is I dont have a sean_customform.xml file

Comment: you have. You may have that in your current package/theme location. normally an external extension holds that file in base/default theme location. search for `sean_customform.xml` file system wide. you can locate it.

Comment: if you dont have that file, then you need to create that file

Comment: I only have that file in app/etc/modules/SeanCustomform.xml but I'm pretty sure thats something completely different

Comment: Sorry this is such a hassle btw, so you want me to add the file but why do I have to add it if it works?  I'm just wondering how does it work if I'm missing that file?

Comment: that is your module's activation file. I am talking about layout update xml file which I explained descriptively above in my answer.

Comment: please provide the link by which you created your module.

Comment: I can't find it that's why I'm asking here :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47929/discussion-between-codingmagesheen-and-rajeev-k-tomy).

Comment: I found it http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1140/adding-custom-layouts-for-cms-and-category-use-with-custom-module-trouble

Answer (score 0):

As per magento functionality when you define **phtm** file in your **xml**, Magento first search it in your current theme.

if file does not exist in current theme template path then it will searching in base theme.

You have to just define phtml file with template file path not full path of phtml file.

Comment: Everything works already. My question is how is the current file path working when I never specified it anywhere?

Comment: Not getting your point.

Comment: Any changes I make to app/code/design/frontend/base/default/template/sean_customform/form.phtml are visible when I visit www.website.com/customform

Comment: I'm asking how does it know to look there when I never specified that file path?

Comment: To clarify what determines where the form.phtml file is?

Comment: You need to view your phtml file changes on browser ?

Comment: No. I just want to know why my form.phtml goes where it is. It works fine I'm just curious for learning purposes why it works there.

Comment: See my update answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically asking us to explain how the layout system works. Once you understand how the xml layout works, you will answer your question.

Explaining the layout system here, now, would just take a bit much. your friend mr google will reveal lots of good resources in this regard.

One such resource is : http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/demystifying-magentos-layout-xml-part-1/

Once you grep the layout system, your ability to change magento to your needs will jump ten fold. You will understand how to manipulate the display layer and adjust the sites visual display in areas without the need to rewrite core blocks.

Using layout directives to change display layer will help later with upgradability.

To many times i have come accross rewrite directives that gets placed on core blocks, which could very easily just be done using layout directives.