# Create completely empty page in Magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, layout-update, page

I am trying to create a completely blank page in Magento, but when I use the "empty" layout, it still has the head, imports, css, etc.

I know that I can update the page layout XML in `CMS > Pages` but I am not sure how that works.

Could anyone please help me with that? What is the easiest way to create a completely blank page in Magento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an empty layout and then select it from the dropdown when you create a page. There are multiple answers on how to do this, check [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1140/adding-custom-layouts-for-cms-and-category-use-with-custom-module-trouble) and [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84969/add-new-page-layout-option-magento).

Basically you are creating a module to create a new layout and make it appear on the layout drowdown, you can use one of the existing ones as a template or create the one you need from scratch.